# Interface whose methods signature refer to an abstract class implementing that interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I am not at all a JAVA expert but I've found that the following code snippets run.

```
interface Arithmetic {
    MyNumber somma(MyNumber b);
    MyNumber sottrai(MyNumber b);
    MyNumber moltiplica(MyNumber b);
    MyNumber dividi(MyNumber b);
}

abstract class MyNumber implements Arithmetic{
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("It works");
    }
}
```

Now in C++ you can do similar things if you do a forward declaration, in Java there's no such thing (to my knowledge) so I don't understand how can Arithmetic be compiled fine despite my `MyNumber` is actually declared after arithmetic. Is there a technicality of Java explaining this?

Comment: Well it's either in the same package or imported from another package.

Comment: If you compile the classes one by one you'll get a compiler error, but in Java you can compile classes as a unit; not just within a package but as an entire module (application or library).

Comment: I feel that in your case it would be more expressive to write `interface Arithmetic<N> { N somma(N other); ... }`. `N` is the generic type of the elements of the set you want to attach the arithmetic operators on. Then `class MySpecificNumber implements Arithmetic<MySpecificNumber>`, if you want the type itself to include the operators. Or `class MySpecificNumber` and `class MyOperators implements Arithmetic<MySpecificNumber>` if you want the operators to be defined independently. This allows e.g. for multiple implementations.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos as I said I've found the code, I didn't design it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java compilation occurs in multiple phases, one of these phases finds all of the declared class symbols and a later phase fills in all the classes' members (except for the already found nested class symbols).

You can read about it here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Enter.java

Comment: It would be nice if you pointed maybe where I need to search for given that in the source code there're 600 lines. Is there a specific bit you want to highlight?

Comment: @user8469759 The Javadoc that starts on line 52 is what I was intending to point out.